# memory leak in NSArray, trace for long time

Tags: ios

There are memory leaks in the below self.listOfCustDetail and self.listOfCustomer

```
-(void) calCustList {
    NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSString  *plistPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"customer.plist"];

    self.listOfCustDetail = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.listOfCustomer = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.customers =  [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] autorelease];

    [self.listOfCustomer removeAllObjects];
    [self.listOfCustDetail removeAllObjects];

    [self.listOfCustomer addObject:@"新紀錄"];
    [self.listOfCustDetail addObject:@""];

    for (id key in self.customers) {
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@", [[self.customers objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0], [[self.customers objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:1], [[self.customers objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:2], [[self.customers objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:3]];
        [self.listOfCustomer addObject:key];
        [self.listOfCustDetail addObject:s];
    }  
}
```

Comment: How do you know there's a leak?

Answer (score 0):

How are your properties definied? do they retain? If they do retain, there is no actual mistake in the piece of code, that you are showing.

How often is that method called? If it is called very often you could use a custom `NSAutoreleasePool`.

Also the following two lines are not needed on a newly initalized array:

```
[self.listOfCustomer removeAllObjects];
[self.listOfCustDetail removeAllObjects];
```

Are you showing the actual sourcecode?

Comment: I can't believe this is the actual sourcecode, because he goes through the effort of creating listOfCustomer and listOfCustDetail and doesn't do anything with them. I agree that if he's leaking, he must be doing some implicit retain in the portion of the code he has not yet shared with us.

Comment: well the data is stored in members.. so perhaps it is the real code.. but anyhow. no mistake in that code.. he needs to show us more / real code.

Comment: Quite right, the method that invokes calCustList may use these ivars. But if he's leaking, it's got to be that these listOfCustomer and listOfCustDetail are being retained somewhere else. May be time for user1324421 to shift-command-B to "Analyze" the code for the proper balancing of allocs/inits and releases. Or start putting in nslog statements that examine your retain counts and the like. Or move to ARC and some of this silliness goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest,enable ARC(auto reference counting) in Project because you no need To release arrays